# Microsoft 2013 excel and or function

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I have two cells B6 and B7. If either of these cells is `Yes` I need cell B9 to be populated with the value `Yes`.

How do I do this?

Comment: In your efforts to solve it, what specific problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your question step by step, because the solution here isn't terribly far from natural language:

*I have two cells B6 and B7. If either of these cells is Yes I need cell B9 to be populated with the value Yes*

*(two cells: B6 and B7). **If** either of these cells **is** "Yes" I need cell B9 to be "Yes"*

***If** either (two cells: B6 and B7) **is** "Yes" I need cell B9 to be "Yes"*

***If** (B6 or B7) **is** "Yes" THEN B9 = "Yes"*

so in B9:  `If (B6 or B7) is "Yes" THEN  "Yes"`

B9 `=If( (B6="Yes" or B7="Yes") THEN  "Yes"  )`

B9 `=If( OR(B6="Yes", B7="Yes") ,  "Yes"   )`

At this point, if you enter this formula in B9, it will work fine when one of the two cells has "Yes" in it.  If neither does, B9 will return *FALSE.*  If instead of *FALSE*, you wanted to see "Watermelon", you would add a third argument to your `IF()` statement.

B9 `=If( OR(B6="Yes", B7="Yes") ,  "Yes" , "Watermelon" )`

If you want the cell to be blank when neither of the others has a "Yes", remove the watermelon and leave just two double-quotes next to each other (like "" )

B9 `=If( OR(B6="Yes", B7="Yes") ,  "Yes" , ""  )`

And this is what the actual Excel formula would be (note that extra spaces have been added for readability; the actual formula doesn't need to contain extra spaces).